# Autofilling keycloak user data from Azure AD after login

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using keycloak to register and login users from Azure AD, I want to link the username and email directly from the Azure AD by following the claim I get from the ID token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference)

Here's my Identity Provider Mapper settings:

[Identity Provider Mapper settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6nXU.png)

Users Group settings:

[Users Group settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY31p.png)

I'd also like to autofill this page with the data I got after the initial problem is solved, this page comes after the first login of a user using login with microsoft

[Review Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCHHL.png)

I've read the keycloak documentation and searched a lot to find an example for a mapper but with no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.